# I am unable to find virtual-box in my dash after installing it through synaptic

Tags: apt, virtualbox, unity-dash, synaptic

I got virtual box 5.02 and its related extension package from synaptic but it's not visible in my dash to open. I know I have it because I followed a terminal prompt link someone gave me here on ask and it revealed:

```
 ~$ apt-cache policy virtualbox
virtualbox:
  Installed: 5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1
  Candidate: 5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.0.18-dfsg-2build1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages .
```

My question is, can it be found in the dash or file folders and subsequently opened, or does it need to be opened through terminal? If the latter, what command-line would I use?

Comment: Log out and log back in or open and close Dash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be related to a known bug.

[Ubuntu 16.04: Dash not showing newly installed apps](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1584422)

Current workaround is to log out and log-back again or reboot.

Comment: Thanks Maki, that did work for virtual-box but the packages from my ubuntu-restricted-extras still don't show. Do you know if that's a separate issue or should I try logging again?

Comment: Hi Jodamo117, I think it's the similar issue with dash not updating its contents, the best thing is to try logging in-out/reboot again. I haven't installed packages from ubuntu-restricted-extras in my machine so I can't verify.

Comment: They're still not showing in dash but are usable from terminal. Not really a big deal though. I'll check the threads and start a new question if necessary. Thanks again for your input Maki.